# background-size: cover stretching on certain phones

Tags: html, css

The background image of the header of my site is stretching and warping in weird ways on certain mobile phones.

[image: mobile view]

Here's the link to the site - [https://jaels-creations-stage.callgage.co/](http://jaels-creations-stage.callgage.co)

Here's the code for the background image, it s a child of the header container:

```
.header .background-image {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-position: center 92%;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  z-index: -1;

  /* On Load Animation */
  opacity: 0;
}
```

I've been trying to figure this out for a long while now, I can't replicate it on my macbook, and with devtools remote devices I can't figure out a proper way to fix it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try height:auto; that will cause css to retain the image's natural aspect ratio

Answer (score 0):

I think is because you need to set the eight to `auto`

```
bg {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    min-height: 100%;
    /* set your own */
    min-width: 1440px;
    /* Set up proportionate scaling */
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    /* Use this if you have your images set to fixed. It will promote the layer */
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}
```

Comment: Just tried this and it had no effect - The .background-image element is an actual `background-image` css property, not an `<img />` tag